# Laravel many to many relations query collection with

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have models:

User belongsToMany group,

User belongsTo class,

User belongsTo grade

Group belongsToMany user

when i do $group->user->with('class') i received an error that collection::with does not exist.

i am trying to achieve a collection of users that belong to the group with the one to many relation information. Any suggestions how this should be done?

Comment: Do you mean `$group->users()->with('class')->get()`?

Comment: wow, that worked! what is the difference when i call users versus users()? on other occasions when i do not need to call further relations it works as well.

Comment: `$group->users()` returns a query builder, `$group->users` directly executes the query and returns the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a relationship query:

```php
$users = $group->users()->with('class')->get();
```